# passing JSON data and getting it back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to passing objects through AJAX, and since I am unsure of both the passing and retrieving, I am having trouble debugging.

Basically, I am making an AJAX request to a PHP controller, and echoing data out to a page. I can't be sure I'm passing my object successfully. I am getting null when printing to my page view.

This is my js:

```
// creating a js filters object with sub arrays for each kind
var filters = {};

// specify arrays within the object to hold the the list of elements that need filtering
// names match the input name of the checkbox group the element belongs to
filters['countries'] = ["mexico", "usa", "nigeria"];
filters['stations'] = ["station1", "station2"];
filters['subjects'] = ["math", "science"];

// when a checkbox is clicked
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {        

    // send my object to server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/results/search_filter',
        success: function(response) {
            // inject the results
            $('#search_results').html(response);
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({filters: filters})
    }); // end ajax setup

});
```

My PHP controller:

```
public function search_filter() {

    // create an instance of the view
    $filtered_results = View::instance('v_results_search_filter');       

    $filtered_results->filters = $_POST['filters'];

    echo $filtered_results;

}
```

My PHP view:

```
<?php var_dump($filters);?>
```

Perhaps I need to use a jsondecode PHP function, but I'm not sure that my object is getting passed in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC the data attribute of the $.ajax jQuery method accepts json data directly, no need to use JSON.stringify here :

```
data: {filters: filters}
```

This way, you're receiving your json data as regular key/value pairs suitable for reading in PHP through the $_POST superglobal array, as you would expect.

Comment: still getting NULL, any other suggestions?

Comment: AFAICT your js code and ajax queries are fine, something must be wrong in your php code and I don't have enough of it to reproduce the issue.

Comment: In the div #search_results, I am getting " NULL " where I expect a printout of the object I'm trying to pass.

Comment: yeah, sorry about overlooking that part of your original post, please read my updated comment above.

Comment: hey you were right, it was my PHP, plus the edit you suggested about leaving out the stringify

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

When you use ajax the page is not reloaded so the php variable isn't of use.

You may want to look for a tutorial to help. I put one at the beginning as I don't see how to format this on my tablet

you will need to json_encode your response as the tutorial shows

you may want to print to a log on the server when you are in the php function and make it world readable so you can access it via a browser

I like to use the developer tools in Chrome to see what is actually returned from the server